# KOGrid - SelectColumnMenu hides behind data

Tags: css, knockout.js, kogrid

I am unable to display SelectColumnMenu when KOgrid has data.
It hides behind the data. I am using knockout 2.2 and kogrid 2.2.1.

Here is the image :

[image]

Comment: can we see some code?

Comment: My KOGrid works fine. It has normal KOGrid rendering code as per the examples. I am using Twitter Bootstrap. The issue is z-index and absolute positioning of the divs. Here is another image if that makes little more sense.

Comment: Some CSS that overrides z-index?

Comment: Until we see the live code or the code in issue, we cannot precisely predict what is the issue.

Comment: Yes I am trying to set z-index of kgColMenu class which displays the column menu selection but it is not getting applied because the div is absolute positioned. Creating the fiddle.

Comment: Here is the fiddle : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/bhoomikakaiya/C4GV7/1/)                             Though in the fiddle it works gr8. But I have too many other CSS's referred. Something else is contradicting. I shall try to replicate the scenario in the fiddle.

Comment: Use Firebug or Chrome console and check the element's associated CSS

Comment: Oh got it fixed. I had messed up with the CSS. Thanks all for the replies.